# Click CommandButton in an other Worksheet by clicking another Command Button

Tags: database, vba, excel

I have several commandbuttons in different sheet. Now I want the user to be able to run all at once if wanted. Therefore I want to use a new CommandButton that runs all CommandButtons in all Worksheets. However I allways get a error message..I have to approaches and have not worked out for me:

running the subs:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonX_Click()


run CommandButtonY_Click

run CommandButtonZ_Click

etc.

end sub
```

..Nothing happens

My other Approach is to select all worksheets and "activate the commmand button", which is always called CommandButton1_Click however I still don´t know how to do it

This was my approach:

```
Sheets(Array("AA", "BB", "CC",etc.).Select
    Sheets("AA").ActivateCall 

Call CommandButton1_Click

End Sub
```

I am new at this, so I would really apreciate your Help!

Thanks!

Jens

Answer (score 3):

This is purely a design opinion, but I would try and tackle this problem a different way.

My preference would be to have my subroutines in a separate module and simply call them from a button.  That is, the _Click event simply looks something like this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Call DoSomeStuff
End Sub
```

While in a separate module all of my subs are grouped accordingly:

```
Sub DoSomeStuff()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "Hooray for VBA"
End Sub
```

Using this method you avoid having to work with VBA's sometimes wonky (In my opinion) event handler and you can re-use subs with the appropriate arguments if they're called by several different buttons.

Then your "Master Button" just calls all the subs:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Call DoSomeStuff
    Call DoSomeMoreStuff
    Call DoTheFinalStuff
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

What error message do you get?

What version of Excel are you running?

This code runs fine in Excel 2007 on Windows 7:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    MsgBox ("Hey there, I'm button 1")
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
    MsgBox ("Hey there, I'm button 2")
End Sub

Sub Button3_Click()
    MsgBox ("Hey there, I'm button 3")
End Sub

Sub Button4_Click()
    Button1_Click
    Button2_Click
    Button3_Click
End Sub
```

I have 3 buttons, each on a different worksheet, and they all display a message that identifies them.  The 4th button is also on a separate worksheet and it displays the other 3 messages one after the other as would be expected.

Can you attach the error message to your post?